# Is this Dependency Injection and/or Singleton Pattern?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, singleton

TL;DR: Whats the difference between Dependency Injection and Singleton Pattern if the injected object is a Singleton?

I'm getting mixed results for how to resolve the design problem I am currently facing.

I would like to have a configuration that is application wide so that different objects and alter the configuration.

I thought to resolve this using a Singleton:

```
class ConfigMeta(type):
    _instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


class Config(metaclass=ConfigMeta):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
```

But searching has shown this to be prone to errors and considered bad practice (when managing class states). Just about every other post suggests using Dependency Injection, but they confuse me on how they do it. They all state "your implementation can be a Singleton, but inject it into other objects in thier constructors".

That would be something along the lines of:

```
# foo.py

from config import Config

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = Config()

# bar.py

from config import Config

class Bar:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = Config()
```

However, each one of those `self.config` refers to the same instance. Hence my confusion...

> How is this considered Dependency Injection and not Singleton Pattern?

If it is considered Dependency Injection, what would it look like as just Singleton Pattern?

Answer (score 2):

With Dependency Injection (DI) you leave it to the DI system to resolve how to get a specific object. You just declare what kind of object you require. This is complementary to the Singleton Pattern where there whole application is served by a single instance of a specific type. So for example:

```
class Config:
    pass

config = Config()  # singleton

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        config = config
```

Here the `Foo` class handles the logic how to get a `Config` object itself. Imagine this object has dependencies itself then this also needs to be sorted out by `Foo`.

With Dependency Injection on the other hand there is a central unit to handle these sort of things. The user class just declares what object it requires. For example:

```
class DI:
    config = Config()

    @classmethod
    def get_config_singleton(cls):
        return cls.config

    @classmethod
    def get_config(cls):
        return Config()

    @classmethod
    def inject(cls, func):
        from functools import partialmethod
        # The DI system chooses what to use here:
        return partialmethod(func, config=cls.get_config())


class Foo:
    @DI.inject  # it's up to the DI system to resolve the declared dependencies
    def __init__(self, config: Config):  # declare one dependency `config`
        self.config = config
```

Comment: So my example of directly instantiating and assigning to the `self.config` attributes of each class is just the Singleton Pattern?

Comment: Further, how is `get_config_singleton()` ever called? This code, as written, will not run (e.g. `f = Foo()` throws `TypeError`).

Comment: @pstatix Yes, if the user class handles its dependencies itself then you're not using dependency injection. However since in your example you get a fresh `Config()` for each instance of `Foo` or `Bar` this isn't the singleton pattern either. `get_config_singleton()` gets called if the DI framework decides to. I gave a very simple example implementation where you'd need to hardcode that switch (i.e. change function names). It was meant to give an idea of what it means that a singleton is injected vs. a fresh instance. Indeed the code should use `partialmethod` instead of `partial` to work.

Comment: @pstatix You can also take a look at the [injector](https://pypi.org/project/injector/) project. The documentation provides a good overview of what dependency injection is and also contains a few links to other resources on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection means providing the constructor the initialized object, in this case the `config`.

The code in your question isn't using dependency injection since the constructor `__init__` doesn't receive the `config` as an argument, so you're only using the singleton pattern here.

See more info [here](http://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/introduction/di_in_python.html) about dependency injection in Python.

Comment: So if `config` was passed as an argument, it would become dependency injection?

Comment: The problem is also that the `Config` object is instantiated very early on and is not accessible at later stages by newer objects that need it.

Comment: @pstatix yes.
 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

the Config is instantiated early but it doesn't matter. You can let the one who constructs the Foo object, be responsible for sending the correct config